# How do I set the $isolated operator on a MongoDB update in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do I set the $isolated operator to a Mongo update in C#?

I can see a way to set pretty much every other update operator....but where the heck is $isolated?  If it's not exposed by the driver, is there a workaround to adding it in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$isolated` is a bit of an oddball as you include it in the query parameter of the `update`.  So using the C# driver you could do something like this:

```
var query = new QueryDocument {
    { "a", 1 },
    { "$isolated", 1}
};
var result = test.Update(query, Update.Inc("b", 2), UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

Comment: Yeah I got so caught up looking for a typed property that I missed the obvious.